# Where can I find out more about this intermittent networking problem for Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2

Jeff Atwood [tweeted on June 11th](http://dvlprs.com/codinghorror/statuses/15913004443): "bah, as I always suspected, our intermittent network problem on Win2k8 Server R2 *was* an OS bug. Non-public kernel hotfix."

We've experienced exactly that same problem, and had to revert some of our new servers to Windows Server 2003. Does anyone know where I can find out more about this problem and how to get the solution? TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Just to state the obvious: contact Microsoft support, especially if you're hoping to get a private hotfix.  IIRC, if you can prove it's a product issue, the call is free (but don't quote me on that, double check for yourself first)